# ASP.NET MVC Kendo UI Edit Popup Internet Explorer Date Edit Problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo UI grid using edit mode popup. Everything works fine until i try to hide a date field from the popup using [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)] now when editing in the popup i get "The field ModifyDate must be a date". It works as expected in Chrome but not in IE.

Controller:

```
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<AdminWasherViewModel>()
                  .Name("grdWasher")
                  .Columns(columns =>
                  {
                      columns.Bound(m => m.WasherItemNumber).Width(70);
                      columns.Bound(m => m.OuterDiameter).Width(100);
                      columns.Bound(m => m.Thickness).Width(85);
                      columns.Bound(m => m.InnerDiameter).Width(100);
                      columns.Bound(m => m.LastModifiedBy).Width(100);
                      columns.Bound(m => m.ModifiedDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss}");

                      columns.Command(command =>
                      {
                          command.Edit();
                          command.Destroy();
                      });
                  })
                  .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
                  .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
                  .Scrollable()
                  .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "dimGrid" })
                  .Sortable()
                  .Pageable(pageable => pageable.PageSizes(true))
                  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                      .Ajax()
                      .Events(events => events
                          .Error("HandleError")
                          .RequestEnd("HandleEndRequest"))
                      .Model(model => model.Id(m => m.WasherID))
                      .Read("ReadWasher", "AdminWasher")
                      .Create("CreateWasher", "AdminWasher")
                      .Update("UpdateWasher", "AdminWasher")
                      .Destroy("DeleteWasher", "AdminWasher"))
                  )
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem. And the Kendo UI is a paid framework...

Answer (score 0):

## The problem

The problem is that when you return a date from your model that date is rendered on the `<input />` with the value:

- "Mon Sep 8 10:56:00 UTC-0300 2014"*

It not occurs when you use it in a NOT HIDDEN input, because Kendo datepicker format the date to:

- "10/08/2014 10:56 AM"*

## Workaround

Unfortunately I have not found a good fix to this bug. A workaround that I found is to **not populate the field**, because with an null value it works.